# Wanting to know the word for 'one rule for me, another for them'

Tags: rules

Is there a single-word term that expresses 'one set of rules/principles for me, and another for everyone else'?  I.e. the opposite of universalising your principles, and what is implied by authoritarianism.

Comment: I simply call it hypocrisy.

Comment: I disagree.  Although I see why you say it.

Comment: Maybe *elitism?*

Comment: If you looked at a few dictionary definitions for 'hypocrisy', you would see why the word is at least hypernymically correct. You need to give some of these definitions, explaining why you'd prefer a different term (one more precise, say).

Comment: Elitism is the correct answer (EDIT: the closest, anyway...).  It's not correct to say it's hypocrisy because you are assuming egalitarianism is implicit.  I can expand on that if you wish.

Comment: the OP can if he wishes answer his own question.

Comment: [Double standard](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double%20standard).

Comment: Maybe.  But if master sits on chair and dog lies on floor, is he holding the dog to a different standard, or is he holding the dog to a single set of standards with two sides?  Namely hierarchy, hygene, and speciesism.

Comment: Double standard as above seems the most logical. However if you want a more complex concept (as implied by authoritarianism), the phrase "All animals are equal, but some animals are more equal than others" might help and should be understood by most readers.

Answer (score 1):

Authoritarianism is often associated with the word 'unfairness' as in the following examples : "Authoritarian rulers today seek to fix outcomes well before election day through laws and policies that embed unfairness…" ; "For one who railed against unfairness when out of office, X needs to curb this tendency toward authoritarianism."